# Unable to connect Sql Server from Asp.net Application - Issue occured frequently

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-administration

Error:

> “System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

While running my ASP.NET application from VS2015, I get error like:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred".

After refreshed its working as usual without any issue so it seems to not work time to time. I am using SQL Express edition with DB size around 6GB.

I couldn't find the cause of the issue. It working fine some time and doesn't working fine some time.

Is it related to max connection in sql express?
DB size?
Sql connection string - connection pooling?

Comment: Just make sure the database server is running. Or check your network. This is a **very** clear error - the web site can't even find the server

Comment: Is this a hosted site? Perhaps you should contact your hoster and find out what's wrong?

Comment: Double check your connection string, and troubleshoot using this link http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Things I usually do when this exception occurs :

1. I check if the parameter `Data Source=MyWebServer` is well filled on my connection string (code problem)
2. I make sure that the server can respond to a ping request (network problem):

> ping MyWebServer;

3. I check if the SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) Service is started on MyWebServer (service problem)

Comment: 1)  & 3) Yes, immediate refresh of error page will work...so no issue in connection string.